# how to use distro live to modify themes

Tags: live-usb, themes

I would like to make changes to desktop theme, if I use a live distro can I install themes and modify colors?

Thank You

Comment: All changes made in Ubuntu live are lost after reboot so I don't know, what exactly and for how long do you want modify. Can you extend your question?

Comment: But if you really want install themes and modify color, you can. It's same as normal distro, but all changes are stored in RAM until reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make any changes in Live USB. It don't support any installation. Any changes in property also will be reset on reboot.

If you want customized USB OS.Try to install directly as mentioned in the below article.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent